# How to dynamically add new row to p:dataTable without validating the form?

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing a form for adding/editing product prices with JSF and PrimeFaces. A single product can have multiple prices depending on volume which is shown in a `<p:dataTable>`.

The backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductBean {

  protected Product product;
  protected List<ProductPrice> productPrices;

  public void addNewPrice() {
    ProductPrice productPrice = new ProductPrice();
    productPrice.setPrice(new BigDecimal(0));
    this.productPrices.add(productPrice);
  }

  // ...
}
```

The Facelet page:

```
<h:form id="productForm">
  <p:inputText value="#{productBean.product.name}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameMessage" />
  </p:inputText>
  <p:message id="nameMessage" for="name" />

  <p:dataTable id="pricesList" ...>
  </p:dataTable>
  <p:commandButton value="Add another price" update="pricesList" action="#{productBean.addNewPrice()}" />
  <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{productBean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

The first button "Add another price" does, what it is supposed to do: Adding a new row to "pricesList". But only if form is valid (form is invalid, if product-name is not set).

My problem is, that I am having two commandButtons for the form, but I don't know how to get my wished functionallity without a commandButton. I tried a lot of ways: Changing the "Add another price" to a standard `<p:button>` with ajax-functionality; doesn't work because of buttons' outcome. I tried "type=button" for this button, but in this case simply nothing happens.

Are there any suggestions have to achieve my wished functionality? It is not necessary to have a button solving my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` submits and processes by default the entire form. This will indeed validate all input fields. You can control this with the `process` attribute which thus defaults to `@form`. In your particular case, you could just use `@this` so that only the command button's own action is invoked.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add another price" process="@this" update="pricesList" action="#{productBean.addNewPrice()}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with using **p:commandButton** to add rows dynamically? 
If i undersatnd your question right, you obviously need a request to your managed bean in order to add your new row information into your datatable list. you could always go for **p:commandLink** if you are not comfortable with **p:commandButton**. and for editing the row data you could use **p:rowEditor** with **p:datatable**.

[check out the showcase example for datatable row editing](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

hope this helps :)

Comment: The two commandButtons themselves are not the problem. My problem is, that the first one, which should only add a new row to the dataTable and refresh a view-id, works like a normal submit-button. Adding a new row with this button does not work, if form is not valid. If form is valid, the button only works once.
Btw, using datatable and rowEditor is exeactly what I want to do.

Comment: @MarcusSchultö welcome to SO. what do you mean by "if form is not valid"?? i did exactly what you want to do in my app. when you click on the Add button you'd call an actionListener in the backing bean which would add another Row object (whatever your datatable row is storing) to your arraylist (which holds the datatable rows). could you post your code behind the add button ??

Comment: I updated the snippets. As you can see, there is an additional inputText "name" in the form. If the name is not set, the form is not valid and no new row is added. If the name is set, a new row is added to "pricesList", but it works only once.

Comment: Url for p:rowEditor showcase example is no longer valid.